# TableView and SearchBar behavior from iOS5 to iOS6 different?

Tags: cocoa-touch, uitableview, uisearchbar, hidden, floating

In my app I use a UITableView and a SearchBar, nothing special.
The SearchBar is added as tableHeaderView

```
self.searchDisplayController.searchBar.delegate = self;
     self.myTableView.tableHeaderView = self.searchDisplayController.searchBar;
```

Than I use the following code to let the SearchBar stay on, so that it don't gets hidden when scrolling.

```
- (void) scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {

    CGRect tableBounds = self.myTableView.bounds;
    CGRect searchBarFrame = self.searchDisplayController.searchBar.frame;

    self.searchDisplayController.searchBar.frame = CGRectMake(tableBounds.origin.x, tableBounds.origin.y, searchBarFrame.size.width, searchBarFrame.size.height);
}
```

This works nice in iOS5 and iOS5.1 but not in iOS6 but I don't know what has changed, does anyone have any ideas?

Help would be higgle appreciated.

SearchBar in iOS5 and iOS5.1
[image: Searchbar in iOS5]

SearchBar in iOS6 is hidden
[image: Searchbar hidden in iOS6]

Comment: Yep - I'm seeing the same thing. Could be something to do with Autolayout. Did you ever solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why it's changed, but it's fairly straightforward to get this working on iOS 6.

Instead of setting the `UISearchBar` as the `tableHeaderView`, use a plain `UIView` instead, then add the search bar as a child of that view.